# How to find the key ID in gpg to use with --export-ssh-key

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnupg

I want to use `gpg --export-ssh-key` but I cannot figure out how to supply the key id. I have the following keys:

```
> gpg --list-keys --keyid-format SHORT
pub   rsa3072/D54EC263 2022-04-30 [SC]
      7EEC0CEDA1346EDFB258D09B5C3AEC88D54EC263
uid         [ultimate] Firstname Lastname <a@b.com>
sub   rsa3072/AAE31E9D 2022-04-30 [E]
```

But none of these seem to work:

```
> gpg --export-ssh-key D54EC263
gpg: key "D54EC263" not found: Unusable public key
gpg: export as ssh key failed: Unusable public key
> gpg --export-ssh-key AAE31E9D
gpg: key "AAE31E9D" not found: Unusable public key
gpg: export as ssh key failed: Unusable public key
> gpg --export-ssh-key 0xD54EC263
gpg: key "0xD54EC263" not found: Unusable public key
gpg: export as ssh key failed: Unusable public key
> gpg --export-ssh-key 0xAAE31E9D
gpg: key "0xAAE31E9D" not found: Unusable public key
gpg: export as ssh key failed: Unusable public key
> gpg --export-ssh-key "rsa3072/D54EC263"
gpg: key "rsa3072/D54EC263" not found: No public key
gpg: export as ssh key failed: No public key
> gpg --export-ssh-key "rsa3072/AAE31E9D"
gpg: key "rsa3072/AAE31E9D" not found: No public key
gpg: export as ssh key failed: No public key
> gpg --export-ssh-key 7EEC0CEDA1346EDFB258D09B5C3AEC88D54EC263
gpg: key "7EEC0CEDA1346EDFB258D09B5C3AEC88D54EC263" not found: Unusable public key
gpg: export as ssh key failed: Unusable public key
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

SSH keys are `A`[uthentication] subkeys, whereas all that currently exists in key `D54EC263` is the main `S`[ign] and `C`[ertify] key with an `E`[ncryption] subkey, so an `A` subkey must be created/added to `D54EC263`.

---

For example:

- ```
  PS $  gpg -K

    C:/Users/JW0914/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/pubring.kbx
    ------------------------------------------------
    sec   rsa4096 2018-12-15 [SC]
          0B6D27185174FF9314DF24A746F7A27A2EAB9D23
    uid           [ultimate] Name <name@email.com>
    ssb>  rsa2048 2018-12-15 [S]
    ssb>  rsa2048 2018-12-15 [E]
    ssb>  rsa2048 2018-12-15 [A]
    ssb   nistp256 2018-12-15 [A]
    ssb   ed25519 2018-12-15 [A]
  ```

  If storing on a hardware key, such as the YubiKey above, only the first `S`, `E`, and `A` subkeys will work *(one key per `S`, `E`, and `A` slot)*; if using multiple SSH keys, ensure most used one is the first `A` subkey.

`gpg --export-ssh-key <hash>` will only export the last `A` subkey [ed25519], so if more than one `A` subkey exists, and the last one is not the one to be exported, use an `!` at the end of the subkey's `<hash>!`:

1. ```
   PS $  gpg --edit-key 2EAB9D23

     Secret key is available.

     sec  rsa4096/46F7A27A2EAB9D23
         created: 2018-12-15  expires: never       usage: SC
         trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
     ssb  rsa2048/67C181BAC34E1EEB
         created: 2018-12-15  expires: never       usage: S
         card-no: 0000 00000000
     ssb  rsa2048/23046D6912055172
         created: 2018-12-15  expires: never       usage: E
         card-no: 0000 00000000
     ssb  rsa2048/29737E4DC004161B
         created: 2018-12-15  expires: never       usage: A
         card-no: 0000 00000000
     ssb  nistp256/4F2AE89500A1ABC4
         created: 2018-12-15  expires: never       usage: A
     ssb  ed25519/17CDD27C70DFA6B7
         created: 2018-12-15  expires: never       usage: A
     [ultimate] (1). Name <name@email.com>

     gpg> quit
   ```
2. ```
   PS $  gpg --export-ssh-key C004161B!

     ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC+hv8siVQ/1miJTMZ5ZuQ/TD8Geg9zNsUCctJloflkFATQ8dexrjHik0kyw+YJE5zlSs8nCQMlwZCbCPJs5aY7nsvUIGgeTmTNvJ3ORaezNTbeJ2Pooa4gCU7XDMS/FwLcIaKd4vsVgBpBfWQKuu/UTbOwlgO2M2vdtOUL5/mwbxu4oSO3miq9v1ylyiPU3UbCVnb7mctDv+IpjhEWIJV6OdNfSzN2jB2XYx4TvvEud5hNqifYjNPdzjm8S4sNuTEZ49m4juGEHAJoSydYdGDz9p3TNDMMlLtQj9VnL+V4mfUVJQy8Ufy1g0KmwcsLDw29Vv/S+0V8eZXRHzrsUktJ openpgp:0xC004161B
   ```

   Whereas without the `!`:

   ```
   PS $  gpg --export-ssh-key C004161B

     ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAICrnfDncMjiXBmoVCwnvTVSF6erVZjtArAXZNMfiG/SR openpgp:0x70DFA6B7
   ```